# Trying to find probability for pair of numbers in list by running through function?

Tags: python

So far far I have it so it print 0.0? but I want my function to return the probability that a wins for each pair in the list. (80,20) player a = 80, player b = 20 etc. I want the list to run through the function any help would be appreciated.

```py
def english_squash(ra,rb):
    A = 'Player A'
    B = 'Player B'

    players = [A, B]

    server = random.choice(players)

    player_a_score = 0
    player_b_score = 0
    round = 0
    total_games = 0

    probability_ra = ra / (ra + rb)
    winning_score = 9

    while player_a_score < winning_score and player_b_score < winning_score:
        probability = random.random()
        round += 1
        if probability <= probability_ra and server == A:
            player_a_score += 1
        elif probability <= probability_ra and server == B:
            server = A

        if probability > probability_ra and server == B:
            player_b_score += 1
        elif probability > probability_ra and server == A:
            server = B

    return (player_a_score, player_b_score, round)   

def winProbabilityEnglish():
    numberlist = [(80,20),(70,30),(60,40),(50,50),(40,60),(30,70),(20,80)]
    for papb in numberlist:
        data = [(english_squash(papb[0], papb[1])) for i in range(10000)]
        for results in data:
            a_wins = 0
            b_wins = 0
            if results[0]> results[1]:
                a_wins += 1
            else:
                b_wins += 1

    prob = a_wins / (a_wins + b_wins)
    return(prob)
```

Comment: could you please format your code properly? There is indent errors everywhere

Comment: `a_wins=0` and `b_wins=0` should be placed before the loops.